# Ramda: convert binary function to arbitrary arity function

Tags: ramda.js

Ramda has cool `or` function, which substitutes `(a, b) => a || b` in composition pipelines. But the point is this is binary function, that accepts only two args. I have a need of using it with any number of args, acting sort of universal `||` operator. `(a, b, c) => a || b || c` Any ideas how to implement that using ramda's toolset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `or` with `reduce`:

```js
reduce(or, false, [0, 0, 42, 0, 1]);
//=> 42
```

However this wouldn't return early as in `0 || 0 || 42 || 0 || 1`. Depending on your dataset this may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a similar function by using R.any with R.identity, and using R.unapply to convert the arguments to an array. However, this function cannot be curried, since the number of parameters is unknown.

```js
const { unapply, any, identity } = R

const fn = unapply(any(identity))

console.log(fn(false, false, false))

console.log(fn(false, false, true))

console.log(fn(false, false, false, true))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can the same thing to emulate R.and with multiple arguments by using R.all:

```js
const { unapply, all, identity } = R

const fn = unapply(all(identity))

console.log(fn(false, false, false))

console.log(fn(false, false, true))

console.log(fn(true, true, true, true))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```